# Netbook running ubuntu 11.10 screen backlight never comes back after it dims

Tags: screen, backlight

My netbook running 11.10 ubuntu goes to sleep after 10 minutes of inactivity as per settings.  After the screens dims, I cannot get the backlight to come back on.  I can see the faint text of the screen. Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: This question is [really a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/872652), and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is already a bug report on Launchpad for your problem and I think that it should be solved soon; if you can't wait, there are some tricks suggested in the comments of that bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/872652